# Fixed Engine, Broke Blinker Relay

Tags: ford, truck, relay, turn-signal, engine-swap

I just picked up my 2000 Ford Ranger from the shop after having the 2.4L engine replaced. The engine seems great so far, but the blinker relay won't stop ticking. It didn't do this at all before the engine was swapped, but I did just upgrade all the lights to LED which included swapping the relay switch, a couple of months ago. I used a cheapo EP27 from Amazon and it worked fine up until this point. I bought a new one from AutoZone to swap it with later tonight, but I'm not convinced that's the problem. **Is there any wiring involved in the engine swap that could have initiated this issue?**

I've read online that the MFS could also be part of the problem, but mine is only a few months old. I did recently have that replaced as well. There also seems to be a new ticking in the speakers when listening to the radio which was also replaced in the last year.

**Any tips or advice for other things to look out for while I'm digging around int he dash?**

Comment: IIRC, if you're hearing it through the speakers, it's usually a sign there's a ground feedback somewhere. This could also be causing the blinkers themselves to be active. I don't know if the work caused it for sure, but when diagnosing a problem which wasn't there before the work was started, you need to look at the work done first as the culprit. IOW: It worked fine before they did the engine swap, so more than likely something they did during the engine swap is probably the cause.

Comment: The relay is clicking, but are the indicators flashing?

Comment: @HandyHowie - No, the lights are off, but turn on when activated by the MFS. Aside from the clicking, everything is functioning as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The relay that I had installed a few months back is notoriously defective. I was surprised that it ever worked to be honest. Someone suggested that the ground wire from the alternator may have been bad, which may have obscured any potential issues with the defective relay. They suggested that fixing the ground wire may have caused the issue to become apparent.

I don't know how accurate that is, but replacing the relay with a better one from AutoZone fixed it, for now at least.

I believe the radio may be unrelated. I never listen to the radio so I just may not have noticed it before, but when listening to it via bluetooth, it works and sounds as it should, which leads me to believe the radio issue may be related to the reception or antenna rather than an electrical problem.

Problem solved, as far as I'm concerned.